# Wso2 5.9 Overriding files

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I try to deploy in a development server a copy of wso2 5.9, when i make changes in for example catalina-server.xml for allow reverse proxy in port 443. All my changes overriding.

I already try add the proxyPort in deployment.toml without success.

```
[server]
hostname = "mydomain.com"
node_ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx..xxx"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"
proxyPort = "443"
```

Can't found in documentation how i should specify this configuration in new toml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort=443
```

Seems this is not documented yet. Figured out looking at the `repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml.j2` file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is documented here under [`Proxy servers`](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/administer/deployment-checklist/) in the deployment checklist

so you should use the following

```
 [transport.https.properties]
 proxyhost= "you.proxy.host"
 proxyPort= "443"
```